# How to loop through data sets to graph particular columns only?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, dataframe

The graph, I have down.
The challenge is I have the _exact_same_code_ for graphing multiple data sets (rather, subsets of one LARGE data set), but I can't seem to get the looping code right to substitute the $ correctly.

Data sets, df1, df2, df3... of the form:

```
OBSDATE     REGION  AVG_RESP  P10  P90
2012-02-01  APAC    1.276     0.78 3.45
2012-02-01  EMEA    2.341     1.23 5.67
2012-02-02  APAC    1.343     0.89 3.21
2012-02-02  EMEA    2.473     1.37 5.98
```

The graph is more complex, but like this:

```
avgMx <- quantile(df1$P90,0.95)
ggplot(df1,aes(x=OBSDATE,y=AVG_RESP))+coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,avgMx))+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=P10,ymax=P90),fill="gray60",alpha=0.33)+geom_line(aes(x=OBSDATE,y=AVG_RESP),color="#007DB1",size=0.5)+facet_wrap(~REGION)
```

if I define a vector or list (both seem to fail with the same error messages) with the data set names I can't get the loop to work to find any descriptive values (like the quantile above or even a max!)

```
filenames <- c("df1","df2","df3")
```

I would like to get something like this to work

```
for (i in filenames) {
   quantile(i$AVG_RESP,0.95)
   max(i$AVG_RESP)
}
```

But I get errors about $ is invalid for atomic vectors.  Upon investigation, that doesn't seem to yield any usable results.

So, I can get this to work:

```
max(df1$AVG_RESP) or max(df1['AVG_RESP'])
```

they both would output 2.473 from above.  However, this doesn't fly:

```
for (i in pagesC) max(i['AVG_RESP'])
```

It does nothing.  Changing it to this:

```
for (i in pagesC) print(max(i['AVG_RESP']))
```

Gives instances of NA.

I'm completely stuck.  Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

EDIT: I fixed the data that was causing errors - should be reproducible now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is a character string; you want the object which has the name that is held in `i`. That is the `get()` function. (untested since what you gave was not reproducible.)

```
for (filename in filenames) {
   i <- get(filename)
   quantile(i$AVG_RESP,0.95)
   max(i$AVG_RESP)
}
```

This is probably not the best way to solve your problem, though. Putting all the data frames in a list and looping over that list with `lapply` might be a better approach (what Tyler described in his answer). Furthermore, if these are subsets you've made of a bigger, single data frame you have, then an even better approach would be to use something from the `plyr` package to define how to split the big data frame up and what to do with each part.

Comment: Brian, thank you for this!  That's exactly what I was looking for, but didn't realize the shortcomings in both my understanding and the available functions.  I'm a recovering SAS user making headway with our new implementation migrating to R.  So, it looks like I won't be able to do what I wanted in this way - for some reason ggplot isn't firing within the loop.  I will dig into plyr and see if that might get the job done.

Comment: @BenH - are you making sure you `print()` the ggplot object? Both ggplot and lattice objects must be printed when used in functions...I'm 99% sure this is a FAQ somewhere, maybe someone will recall for us.

Comment: You are right, Chase.  Must have overlooked that portion of the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't reproducible so this is my best guess at what you want:

```
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- read.table(text="OBSDATE     REGION  AVG_RESP  P10  P90
2012-02-01  APAC    1.276     0.78 3.45
2012-02-01  EMEA    2.341     1.23 5.67
2012-02-02  APAC    1.343     0.89 3.21
2012-02-02  EMEA    2.473     1.37 5.98
2012-02-01  APAC    1.276     0.78 3.45
2012-02-01  EMEA    2.341     1.23 5.67
2012-02-02  APAC    1.343     0.89 3.21
2012-02-02  EMEA    2.473     1.37 5.98
2012-02-01  APAC    1.276     0.78 3.45
2012-02-01  EMEA    2.341     1.23 5.67
2012-02-02  APAC    1.343     0.89 3.21
2012-02-02  EMEA    2.473     1.37 5.98", header=TRUE)

info <- function(dataframe){
    c(quantile(dataframe$AVG_RESP,0.95), max(dataframe$AVG_RESP))
}

LIST <- list(df1, df2, df3)
lapply(LIST, info)   
#Or you may want to use sapply if you want it to return a matrix
sapply(LIST, info)
```

R can use loops but this really isn't the R way of doing things.

Comment: I'm very curious why it isn't "reproducible" - the only thing I changed was the dataframe name and included less data.  Everything else is code that runs for me - minus the loop, of course.

Comment: Yeah ben I figured out what was wrong.  I thought it was too little data that was giving me an error and it's that there's a small tick mark at the end of your data that barely shows up when I cut and paste but causes an error to be thrown up.  That's why I pasted a bunch of your data sets together but this was not necessary.

Comment: PS I know you want to use a loop but I really would recommend you become comfortable with the apply family of functions.

Comment: So, the tick was an artifact of trying to get my stuff to display correctly here.

I'm trying to _learn_ R, but I'm also trying to get work done in the way that makes sense to me.  I'll start digging into the apply family.