# how to add id variable to multiple datasets in R

Tags: r, variables, loops, dataset

Using R, I would like to add a counter variable (id variable) to a number of datasets. For example I have two datasets x.df and y.df:

```
x1   <- c(1,3,5,7)
x2   <- letters[1:4]
x.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1, x2))

y1   <- c(100,200,300,400,500)
y2   <- c(letters[22:26])
y.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(y1, y2))
```

To these datasets I would like add an id variable, "id":

```
datasets <- c("x.df","y.df")

for (i in datasets) {
  i$sortid <- c(1:nrow(i))
}
```

This results in the error:

> Error in 1:nrow(i) : argument of length 0

I think what is causing the error is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114376/how-to-loop-through-data-sets-to-graph-particular-columns-only) by Brian Diggs, who notes: i is a character string; you want the object which has the name that is held in i. That is the get() function.

However, I am unsure how to apply the get function to the elements of the "datasets". Also I don't think lapply is appropriate here, since I want to add a variable not to output a list, but maybe I'm wrong?

Any comments are appreciated,

Richard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (i in datasets)
{
    d <- get(i)
    d$sortid <- 1:nrow(d)
    assign(i, d)
}
```

But the REAL answer is to wrap your datasets in a list:

```
dfs <- lapply(list(x.df, y.df), function(d) {
     d$sortid <- 1:nrow(d)
     d
})
```

Comment: +1 too fast! This was my exact answer including using a `list` and `lapply`.

Comment: Thank you very much for these two solutions. Both of them work like a charm. I recognize that in R the lapply solutions are preferred above 'loop-soltions', but I find it difficult to handle datasets when they are in put in a list format. (For example, to do analysis on one of them, or to write them in .txt format.) I guess I'll have to work on my lapply skills! ;) Thanks again!